# no value given for one or more required parameters in vb.net i have use Ms Access when cust_id assign 1 then no error when assign 0 then occur error

Tags: vb.net

No value given for one or more required parameters in vb.net. I have used MS Access when `cust_id` assign 1 then no problem; when assign 0 then error
would occur.

```
  Try
   con.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=Pradnya_DataB.mdb"
   con.Open()
   dt = New DataTable
   DS = New DataSet
   ss = "Select cust_id from Customer"
   da = New OleDbDataAdapter(ss, con)
   da.Fill(DS, "Customer")
   TextBox2.DataSource = DS.Tables("Customer")
   TextBox2.ValueMember = "cust_id"
   TextBox2.DisplayMember = "cust_id"
 Catch ex As Exception
     MsgBox(ex.Message)
 Finally
     dt.Clear()
     con.Close()
  End Try
```

Comment: At which statement, you are getting error ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Could you provide more details? If you're not comfortable writing in English, you could ask a friend to proof-read it for you. At the moment, it's unclear exactly what you asking. See [How to ask?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for more information.